# How can I htmlfontify an Emacs buffer with composed characters preserved?

Tags: emacs

How can I htmlfontify a code buffer in Emacs without losing the composed characters?

I have several modes that display certain ASCII sequences as unicode using `compose-region`. For example, I might write something like:

```
foo :: Num a => [a] -> a
foo = foldl (+) 0 . map (\ x -> x + f x - 10)
```

and the editor displays (without changing the buffer's actual contents):

```
foo ∷ Num a ⇒ [a] → a
foo = foldl (+) 0 ∘ map (λ x → x + f x - 10)
```

This is essentially another form of syntax highlighting, except with special characters instead of colors.

However, when I use `M-x htmlfontify-buffer` on a buffer that looks like my second example, all this information is lost and the html output looks like the first version. How can I avoid losing the character transformations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think htmlfontify supports this feature yet.  But if you `M-x report-emacs-bug` to request the feature, you might find someone who can implement it fairly quickly (then again, maybe not).